# converting an tictactoe app from console to javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I've been struggling these past few days with something, but cannot get it to work. I'm beaten.

I wrote a simple tic tac toe java console app, as part of me learning java. I works. I was a nice challenge and I managed to implement a minimax AI thing, which makes it pretty much unbeatable.

However, I wanted to take it a step further, and make it a javafx app. I did a little fx during a course, and I thought I'd give it a go. To keep it simple, I decided for an extremely simple layout, namely a 9 button layout, for which I intented to manipulate the buttontext.

However, I've been struggling and cannot get some key features to work in the controller, namely a binding (between my 9 board.cells and the 9 buttons - the buttons should have it's text binded the the cell.visual attribute) and a listener (listening to game.nextturn - when it's the users turn, I want to enable the buttons and vice versa).
Both things being essential, I am not getting any further.

I am hoping you guys can get me on the right track here. I would greatly appreciate it!

So the most important classes (excl. getters and setters) are below.
PS. THe project is also available on github: https://github.com/drstruggle/TicTacToe_To_Fx.

Regards Struggle!

Game class, holding the current board, the two players (computer and user)

```
public class Game {

    //variables
    private Board currentBoard;
    private Computer computer;
    private Player player;

    public Game(Player player, State nextMove ){
        currentBoard = new Board(nextMove);
        this.player = player;
        this.computer = new Computer();
    }

    //player - computer- makes a move
    public void computerMove(){

        //create the illusion of time spent thinking
        System.out.println("Computer makes his move.");

        //here comes the boom.. this is the AI at work
        //MiniMax.run(State.O, this.currentBoard, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        computer.run(State.O, this.currentBoard, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);

    }
```

The board (holding the 3x3 cells and the status - gameover, gamewon, movesdone and nextturn)

```
public class Board {

    //variables
    private Cell[][] cells;
    private List<Cell> availableMoves;
    private boolean gameWon;
    private boolean gameOver;
    private State whoWon;
    private int movesDone;
    private SimpleObjectProperty<State> nextTurn;

    public Board(State nextTurn) {
        cells = new Cell[3][3];
        cells[0][0] = new Cell(1,0,0);
        cells[0][1] = new Cell(2,0,1);
        cells[0][2] = new Cell(3,0,2);
        cells[1][0] = new Cell(4,1,0);
        cells[1][1] = new Cell(5,1,1);
        cells[1][2] = new Cell(6,1,2);
        cells[2][0] = new Cell(7,2,0);
        cells[2][1] = new Cell(8,2,1);
        cells[2][2] = new Cell(9,2,2);
        this.gameWon=false;
        this.gameOver=false;
        this.movesDone=0;
        this.nextTurn = new SimpleObjectProperty<State>(nextTurn);
        this.availableMoves = getAvailableMoves();
    }

    //make a move, make nextTurn owner of the cell

    public void move(Cell movedCell){

        //System.out.println("IN MOVE - MOVED CELL = "+ movedCell.getVisual());
        //set the owner
        this.cells[movedCell.getR()][movedCell.getC()].setOwner(getNextTurn());

        //set remaining available moves
        getAvailableMoves();

        //add one moveDone
        setMovesDone(getMovesDone()+1);

        //set next player
        setNextTurn((getNextTurn()==State.X ? State.O : State.X));

        //check if the game is over
        checkIfGameIsOver();

    }

    //get all available cells left
    public List<Cell> getAvailableMoves() {

        //get free slots
        List<Cell> availableMoves = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int r = 0; r < getCells().length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < getCells()[0].length; c++) {
                if (this.cells[r][c].getOwner()== State.EMPTY) {
                    availableMoves.add(this.cells[r][c]);
                }
            }
        }
        this.availableMoves = availableMoves;
        return availableMoves;
    }

    //check if there's a winner, or all slots are owned
    public void checkIfGameIsOver(){

        //check for winners

        // horizontal
        for (int r = 0; r < cells.length; r++) {
            if (isThisARow(cells[r][0], cells[r][1], cells[r][2])) {
                this.gameWon = true;
                this.gameOver = true;
                this.whoWon = cells[r][0].getOwner();
            }
        }

        //vertical
        for (int c = 0; c < cells[0].length; c++) {
            if (isThisARow(cells[0][c], cells[1][c], cells[2][c])) {
                this.gameWon = true;
                this.gameOver = true;
                this.whoWon = cells[0][c].getOwner();
            }
        }

        //diagonal
        if (isThisARow(cells[0][0], cells[1][1], cells[2][2])) {
            this.gameWon = true;
            this.gameOver = true;
            this.whoWon = cells[0][0].getOwner();
        }
        if (isThisARow(cells[2][0], cells[1][1], cells[0][2])) {
            this.gameWon = true;
            this.gameOver = true;
            this.whoWon = cells[2][0].getOwner();
        }

        //check if all slots are filled
        if(isBordIsVol()){
            this.gameWon = false;
            this.gameOver = true;
        }
    }

    //helper for 3-in-a-row
    public boolean isThisARow(Cell pos1, Cell pos2, Cell pos3){
        return (pos1.getOwner()!=State.EMPTY && (pos1.getOwner() == pos2.getOwner() && pos2.getOwner() == pos3.getOwner()));
    }
```

and the cell (being used by the board, holding the owner etc)

```
public class Cell {

    private final int shortCode;
    private State owner;
    private final int r;
    private final int c;
    private String visual;


    public Cell(int shortCode, int r, int c) {
        this.shortCode = shortCode;
        this.r = r;
        this.c = c;
        setOwner(State.EMPTY);
    }
```

and the most important class:

```
public class VisualController {

    @FXML
    private GridPane tttbox;

    @FXML
    private Button button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, startNewGame;
    private ObservableList<Button> activeButtons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private Game game;
    private List<Game> games = new ArrayList<>();

    @FXML
    public void initialize() { }

    public void changeListenerTurn(){

        SimpleObjectProperty nextTurn = this.game.getCurrentBord().getNextTurnProperty();

        nextTurn.addListener(new javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener<State>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> observableValue, State state, State t1) {
                System.out.println("next turn changed");
                if (t1 == State.X) {
                    //player turn
                }else{
                    //computer turn
                    game.computerMove();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void bindButtonsWithCells(){

        button1.textProperty().bind(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[0][0].getVisualProperty());
        button2.textProperty().bind(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[0][1].getVisualProperty());
        button3.textProperty().bind(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[0][2].getVisualProperty());
        button4.textProperty().bind(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[1][0].getVisualProperty());
        button5.textProperty().bind(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[1][1].getVisualProperty());
        button6.textProperty().bind(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[1][2].getVisualProperty());
        button7.textProperty().bind(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[2][0].getVisualProperty());
        button8.textProperty().bind(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[2][1].getVisualProperty());
        button9.textProperty().bind(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[2][2].getVisualProperty());
    }

    public void addActiveButtons(){
        activeButtons.add(button1);
        activeButtons.add(button2);
        activeButtons.add(button3);
        activeButtons.add(button4);
        activeButtons.add(button5);
        activeButtons.add(button6);
        activeButtons.add(button7);
        activeButtons.add(button8);
        activeButtons.add(button9);
    }

    public void disableActiveButtons(){

        for(Button b: activeButtons){
            b.setDisable(true);
        }
    }

    public void enableActiveButtons(){

        for(Button b: activeButtons){
            b.setDisable(false);
        }
    }

    public void onButtonClicked(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("button clicked");
        if(this.game.getCurrentBord().getNextTurn()==State.X) {
            if (e.getSource().equals(button1)) game.getCurrentBord().move(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[0][0]);
            if (e.getSource().equals(button2)) game.getCurrentBord().move(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[0][1]);
            if (e.getSource().equals(button3)) game.getCurrentBord().move(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[0][1]);
            if (e.getSource().equals(button4)) game.getCurrentBord().move(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[1][0]);
            if (e.getSource().equals(button5)) game.getCurrentBord().move(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[1][1]);
            if (e.getSource().equals(button6)) game.getCurrentBord().move(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[1][2]);
            if (e.getSource().equals(button7)) game.getCurrentBord().move(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[2][0]);
            if (e.getSource().equals(button8)) game.getCurrentBord().move(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[2][1]);
            if (e.getSource().equals(button9)) game.getCurrentBord().move(game.getCurrentBord().getCells()[2][2]);
        }
    }

    public void onStartNewGamePressed(){

        //initialize game with correct first player
        System.out.println("Game " + (games.size() + 1) + " :");
        if (games.size() % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("\nComputer has O and goes first. You have X\n");
            this.game = new Game(new Player("Player"), State.O);
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nYou have X and go first. Computer has O.\n");
            this.game = new Game(new Player("Player"), State.X);
        }
        this.games.add(game);
        addActiveButtons();
        bindButtonsWithCells();
        changeListenerTurn();
        startGame();
    }

    public void startGame() {

        if (game.getCurrentBord().getNextTurn() == State.O) {
            game.computerMove();
        } else {
            //player move
            //enable activebuttons
        }

        checkIfGameIsOver();

    }

    public void checkIfGameIsOver(){
        //resume game result
        if(game.isGameOver()){

            if(game.isGameWon()){
                if(game.getWhoWon() == State.X){
                    System.out.println("\n\nYou have won!!! Nice work!");
                    game.getPlayer().setWinsPlayer(game.getPlayer().getWinsPlayer()+1);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("\n\nGame over. Computer has won!!!");
                    game.getPlayer().setWinsComputer(game.getPlayer().getWinsComputer()+1);
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("\n\nGame over. It's a tie.");
                game.getPlayer().setTies(game.getPlayer().getTies()+1);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

And the fx itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<GridPane fx:id="tttbox" alignment="center" hgap="10" prefHeight="320" prefWidth="320" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="tictactoe.controller.VisualController">

    <VBox>
        <HBox prefHeight="100">
            <Button fx:id="button1" onAction="#onButtonClicked" prefHeight="100" prefWidth="100" style="-fx-font-size: 4em;" text="1" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <Button fx:id="button2" onAction="#onButtonClicked" prefHeight="100" prefWidth="100" style="-fx-font-size: 4em;" text="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <Button fx:id="button3" onAction="#onButtonClicked" prefHeight="100" prefWidth="100" style="-fx-font-size: 4em;" text="3" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
        </HBox>

        <HBox prefHeight="100">
            <Button fx:id="button4" onAction="#onButtonClicked" prefHeight="100" prefWidth="100" style="-fx-font-size: 4em;" text="4" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Button fx:id="button5" onAction="#onButtonClicked" prefHeight="100" prefWidth="100" style="-fx-font-size: 4em;" text="5" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Button fx:id="button6" onAction="#onButtonClicked" prefHeight="100" prefWidth="100" style="-fx-font-size: 4em;" text="6" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        </HBox>

        <HBox prefHeight="100">
            <Button fx:id="button7" onAction="#onButtonClicked" prefHeight="100" prefWidth="100" style="-fx-font-size: 4em;" text="7" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Button fx:id="button8" onAction="#onButtonClicked" prefHeight="100" prefWidth="100" style="-fx-font-size: 4em;" text="8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Button fx:id="button9" onAction="#onButtonClicked" prefHeight="100" prefWidth="100" style="-fx-font-size: 4em;" text="9" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        </HBox>

    </VBox>
   <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
      <children>
         <Button fx:id="startNewGame" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onStartNewGamePressed" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="300.0" text="Start new game" />
      </children>
   </VBox>

    <padding>
      <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
   </padding>

</GridPane>
```

Comment: It would have been easier, less verbose, repetitive, to do JavaFX without FXML here. I would still make a simple two `Button` prototype with a `SimpleObjectProperty<Cell>`, and such - more clear that way.

Comment: @JoopEggen, FXML is fine giving that a TicTacToe board is mostly static.

Comment: @drstruggle, I would suggest not trying to connect your console app to a GUI. I think you should build your GUI from the ground up. Use some of the ideas from your console app in your GUI app. [Here](https://github.com/sedj601/TicTacToeFX_2/blob/master/src/tictactoefx_2/FXMLDocumentController.java) is one I implemented with the AI based on http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch10/ttt.html.

Comment: What does `getVisualProperty()` do? There doesn't seem to be any observable property in the `Cell` class for you to bind the text to.